# Smooth Boundary Extraction from a Binary Image

Tags: python, math, image-processing, scientific-computing, scikit-image

I'm trying to extract the boundary between two regions in an image programmatically. I've got the hard bits figured out, so that I have a binary image that contains the boundary and plenty of noise.
[image: Sample Image]. Cropping the areas outside isn't an issue.

The boundary in the image is afflicted both by noise (bottom-left for example) and some areas of discontinuity. That means I can't simply select the shape based on one known pixel.

The problem left to me is pretty simple - I only really need to fill the gaps in the boundary and smooth it out, so that I am left with something smooth and continuous that I can extract afterwards. That doesn't sound like a particularly hard problem for images like this, but I'm completely lost. What algorithms or strategies could I possible use in order to turn this image into something useful?

The output I'm looking for is something that can be cropped to give [image: Sample Output].

Comment: From the description above, it's not entirely clear what you'd like as output.  Could you give a graphical example?

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt, I added an example

Answer (score 0):

An common practice is to use a [gaussian blur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur). This will filter out the noise in the image depending on the intensity of the blur. At the bottom of the article there is a gif with a cat image showing what you want.

After that there are contour finding algos which could help you extract the boundaries as pixel chains

Comment: Contour finding is probably the best bet here, given that the input image is fairly noisy.  You need a method that will integrate over the structure you are looking for.